# How to offset/shift a Pandas Dataframe into another year?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, time-series, offset

I have the following 15 minute data as a dataframe for 3 years. With the first two columns being the index.

```
2014-01-01 00:15:00  1269.6      
2014-01-01 00:30:00  1161.6      
2014-01-01 00:45:00  1466.4      
2014-01-01 01:00:00  1365.6      
2014-01-01 01:15:00  1362.6      
2014-01-01 01:30:00  1064.0      
2014-01-01 01:45:00  1171.2      
2014-01-01 02:00:00  1171.0      
2014-01-01 02:15:00  1330.4      
2014-01-01 02:30:00  1309.6      
2014-01-01 02:45:00  1308.4      
2014-01-01 03:00:00  1494.0
```

I would like to offset/shift the data into the previous year so that     `2014-01-01 00:15:00  1269.6`  will be converted into     `2013-01-01 00:15:00  1269.6` .

I have used
    df = df.shift(-1, freq='15min')
to shift the dataframe 15 mins into the past but would not like to offset/shift by the number of 15min intervals as this might cause errors in leap years and with clock changes.

Does anyone have a smooth solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

```
In [13]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,1),index=date_range('20140101 00:15:00',freq='15T',periods=10))

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                            0
2014-01-01 00:15:00 -0.176117
2014-01-01 00:30:00  0.517030
2014-01-01 00:45:00  1.033585
2014-01-01 01:00:00 -0.284402
2014-01-01 01:15:00  0.476984
2014-01-01 01:30:00  0.356078
2014-01-01 01:45:00 -0.285609
2014-01-01 02:00:00  0.423048
2014-01-01 02:15:00  0.095823
2014-01-01 02:30:00 -1.123258

In [15]: df.index = df.index-pd.offsets.Day(365)

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
                            0
2013-01-01 00:15:00 -0.176117
2013-01-01 00:30:00  0.517030
2013-01-01 00:45:00  1.033585
2013-01-01 01:00:00 -0.284402
2013-01-01 01:15:00  0.476984
2013-01-01 01:30:00  0.356078
2013-01-01 01:45:00 -0.285609
2013-01-01 02:00:00  0.423048
2013-01-01 02:15:00  0.095823
2013-01-01 02:30:00 -1.123258
```

Comment: I don't really like the answer, I think subtracting a year should work....going to open an issue

Comment: This works but I agree with you, it would be great if one could shift/offset it by a year. `df.index = df.index-pd.offsets.YearBegin(1)` or `df.index = df.index-pd.offsets.YearEnd(1)` deliver similar results like `df = df.shift(-1, 'A') `

Comment: I created an issue about this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4804, but not entirely sure it is a bug, as what you are doing is changing the frequency of the series beforehand then subtracting 1 year, which is 'correct'

Comment: Shifting by exactly a year is useful, especially when your time series is seasonal. The offset-by-365-day method misses leap years

Comment: If you do this, the day of week may change.  Further, if an observation is near a holiday, shifting by 365 days may not put you in the same position relative to the holiday.